# Duplicates while using loop to print a substring

Tags: python-2.7

I need to find lines that starts with "From" in a file and print the second string in that line. I wrote the following code. I got the output but everything is duplicated. Why that happens? Somebody please help

```
count=0
line=' '
fh=open("mbox-short.txt")
while True:
   f=fh.readline()
   if f=='':
       break
   else:
       if f.find("From")!=-1:
           count+=1
           print f.split(" ")[1]

print "There were", count, "lines in the file with From as the first word"
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'duplicated'? It's working fine on my system.

Comment: gsilver@umich.edu
gsilver@umich.edu

gsilver@umich.edu
gsilver@umich.edu

zqian@umich.edu
zqian@umich.edu

gsilver@umich.edu
gsilver@umich.edu

wagnermr@iupui.edu
wagnermr@iupui.edu

zqian@umich.edu
zqian@umich.edu     This is a sample output. I got everything duplicated

Comment: What's the input file corresponding to this output?

Comment: http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt . This link contains the sample input

Comment: It isn't being duplicated. The output is correct. Read the input file carefully.

Comment: What should I do to get each email id once?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106270/discussion-between-elantra-and-anmol-singh-jaggi).